# Shared filesystem location on Android

Tags: android, permissions, filesystems

is there a location on the Android filesystem that any program can read and write? In other words, if I need to generate a file in my app and give it to the user, where can I place it? Let's assume the user has a file manager (Astro or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common place is sd-card which is called [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) in android.